# Visual Studio .exe won't run program

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, runtime, exe

I am having a bit of trouble running my C++ program as a `.exe` file. It takes in one input file (specified in project properties > debugger: `< input.txt`) and outputs two files.

When I run the program within Visual Studio itself, everything completes just fine. The files being written are correct. However, when I try to run the `.exe` file, it does not seem to do anything.

Project name = `test`

I am running the `.exe` from: `test\Debug\test.exe`. That's the only location within the VS project folder that I see an `.exe` file. I have also moved the expected `input.txt` to this same location. Can anyone help me troubleshoot?

Comment: When you execute the app from the command line are you supplying the filename as an argument exactly like you do with the debugger?

Comment: `< input.txt` looks suspiciously like input redirection. That's normally done by CMD.EXE. When you're running your EXE from Visual Studio instead of CMD.EXE, Visual studio will do so. But how exactly are you starting the EXE outside of Visual Studio? Double clicking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are passing input.txt as an argument to the program. In this case you have to start the program like this:

`test.exe < input.txt`

That's what VS does for you when you debug the program. Putting the file next to the program is not the same as passing an argument.

Comment: Thank you very much. Running from the command-line works just fine for me. It seems that my TA is unable to run the program this way for some reason. Would there be any compatibility issues if the `.exe` is built with VS2012 and the machine that tries to run the `.exe` only has VS2010?

Comment: If the machine has Visual Studio, chances are you have whatever you need to run the program. However, VS2012 introduces a new runtime which is not available on older machines so you might have to install the Visual C++ Runtime 2012 first.

Comment: You can download the runtime [here](http://www.microsoft.com/de-at/download/details.aspx?id=30679). The redistributable packages should also be located in the Visual Studio Installation directory.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I will pass this along and see if that resolves the problem.

Comment: @MSalters - thanks for the edit, it seems I have missed the '<'. So it's not really a program argument but rather input passed to the program on startup.